# Nesting ng-repeat three times or more?

Tags: json, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Lets say we have the following JSON file:

```
{
  "MainRegister": {
    "description": "Hello World",
    "identifier": "01",
    "specifications": [
      {
        "usage": "Retail",
        "other": {
          "type": "Finance",
          "included": "True"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

How do I now access the deepest field *included* when going through ng-repeat? I tried the following:

```
<div ng-repeat="entry in entries">
    {{entry.description}}
    <span ng-repeat="specs in entry.specifications">
      {{specs.usage}}
      <span ng-repeat="subspecs in specs.other">
        {{subspecs.included}}
      <span/>
    <span/>

</div>
```

When doing so, {{entry.description}} and {{specs.usage}} will work and displays "Hello World" and "Retail". However, {{subspecs.included}} does not work.... Moreover, when nesting more than two times then we get a problem. What is the solution for this? Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Other` is an `object`, not a `collection`...

```
"other": {
          "type": "Finance",
          "included": "True"
      }
```

So, you could output `specs.other.included` ?

```
<div ng-repeat="entry in entries">
    {{entry.description}}
    <span ng-repeat="specs in entry.specifications">
      {{specs.usage}}
      <br />
      {{subspecs.other.included}}

    <span/>
</div>
```

EDIT: based on comment

does it make sense to have `other` as a collection? will you have

```
"other": [{
              "type": "Finance",
              "included": "True"
          },
          {
              "type": "Sport",
              "included": "False"
          }
]
```

if not, then leave it as is, and just remove the last `ng-repeat`.

Comment: If other was a collection, would it then work? And indeed the solution seems to be just to call it by specs.other.included. Thank you